# Inconsistent pip script naming

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, easy-install

How do you get `easy_install` to create a consistently named `pip` executable?

On a desktop install of Ubuntu 12.10, if I run:

```
wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py -O /tmp/ez_setup.py
python /tmp/ez_setup.py -U setuptools
```

this creates the script `/usr/local/bin/pip2.7`.

But if I run the **exact same command** in an Ubuntu 12.10 EC2 AMI, it creates the script `/usr/local/bin/pip-2.7`.

Note the extra dash.

This is complicating my attempts to build deployment and test scripts for different Python versions because I can't predict what the appropriate pip executable will be named. I might have expected this across different distros, but both environments are using the same version of Ubuntu...yet have different results.

How do I fix this?

Comment: not a fix... but you might have better luck with: 'apt-get install python-pip' to get a compatible version

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg With using `apt-get install python-pip` I have always problem, that on older versions of OS (including Ubuntu 12.10) I get rather outdated version of `pip`. As `pip` and `setuptools` undergo significant updates in last 2 years, it makes using it difficult.

Comment: you can also: 'apt-get install python-setuptools', which will give you easy_install.  Then: 'easy_install pip'